# Groovy closures not handling exceptions

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

In Katalon Studio, I am trying to write a test case with a closure to help deal with the limitations of the supported selectors. My code for it is thus:

```
def findDataRows = {
    WebElement container 
    try {
        container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('.tab-pane.active'))
    }   
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex) { 
        container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('.dataTables_wrapper'))
    }
    String dataRowsSelector = '.dataTables_scrollBody tbody tr:not(.dataTables_empty):not(.group)'

    List<WebElement> tableRows = container.findElements(By.cssSelector(dataRowsSelector)),
        dataRows = new LinkedList<WebElement>()
    for (WebElement tr : tableRows) {
        if (tr.findElements(By.cssSelector('.dataTables_empty')).empty) {
            dataRows.add(tr)
        }
    }
    dataRows
}
```

For some reason, instead of the `catch` block handling the `NoSuchElementException` that gets thrown, and setting `container` to an element in my test case that is guaranteed to exist, the compiler simply complains at the `try` block, despite its existence.

How do I get Groovy to handle exceptions in closures?

**NOTE**: It's supposed to `return dataRows`

Comment: `complains`.. please edit your question and provide exception with stacktrace you have